# Por que minha aplicação está fazendo logout após salvar um registro? - Asp.net MVC e Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity-server

Quando eu criei minha app (Asp.net core MVC) pela primeira vez, o Identity foi instalado automaticamente. Todo os recursos de login, registros de usuários, dentre outros, foram criados automaticamente.

Quando eu fao o login usando meu e-mail, tudo parece estar funcionando 100%, mas quando abro uma página de  cadastro e cadastro um registro e clico no botão salvar, o sistema está salvando o registro e logo em seguida, está fazendo logout. Não entendo pq está desconectando o usuário... Não faço a mínima ideia de onde ele esteja chamando o a action Logout. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Obrigado :)

Controller Account (Criada Automaticamente pelo Asp.net)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("account/logout")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

Controller do Cadastro de Países

```
//[Authorize]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class PaisController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IPaisAppService _paisAppService;

    public PaisController(IPaisAppService paisAppService,
                             INotificationHandler<DomainNotification> notifications) : base(notifications)
    {
        _paisAppService = paisAppService;
    }       

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Policy = "CanWritePaisData")]
    [Route("pais-gerenciar/cadastrar-novo")]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(_paisAppService.CreateNew());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Policy = "CanWritePaisData")]
    [Route("pais-gerenciar/cadastrar-novo")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(PaisViewModel paisViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(paisViewModel);

        int paisId = _paisAppService.Register(paisViewModel);

        if (IsValidOperation())
            ViewBag.Sucesso = "País cadastrado!";

        if (paisId > 0)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            TempData["SucessoNew"] = ViewBag.Sucesso;

            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Pais", new { id = paisId});
        }

        return View(paisViewModel);

    }       
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Policy = "CanWritePaisData")]
[Route("pais-gerenciar/cadastrar-novo")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(PaisViewModel paisViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(paisViewModel);

    int paisId = _paisAppService.Register(paisViewModel);

    if (IsValidOperation())
        ViewBag.Sucesso = "País cadastrado!";

    if (paisId > 0)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();

        TempData["SucessoNew"] = ViewBag.Sucesso;

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Pais", new { id = paisId});
    }

    return View(paisViewModel);

}

[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "CanWritePaisData")]
[Route("pais-gerenciar/editar-pais/{id:int}")]
public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var pais = _paisAppService.GetById(id.Value);

    if (pais == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (TempData["SucessoNew"] != null)
        ViewBag.Sucesso = TempData["SucessoNew"];

    return View(pais);
}
```

Comment: Após o cadastro, você está fazendo um “RedirectToAction” para Edit pais, veja o Authorize e bem provável que não tenha permissão da pagina de editar, ai ele retornar para o login.

Comment: Sim, após criar o registro, estou fazendo o RedirectTo Action. Editei o post.

Comment: Após salvar o sistema faxz logout e redireciona para home/index... estranho, pois ele não redireciona para login....

Comment: então faz uma altração em return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Pais", new { id = paisId});, pede para redirecionar para outro página, porque o problema esta neste ponto

Comment: Então @itasouza, mesmo seguindo sua sugestão, o problema persiste. Parece que tem algo limpando o cookie... Não faço a mínima ideia...